# How to check if restored database is the same as original

Tags: backup, oracle-11g

Is there a way to check if restored backup of Oracle database is the same as the original database? Is there a simple way to check it if I have the original database?

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL Developer, Tools - Database Diff, this would give you an idea. There is a tutorial here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52sqldev-1735911.html. Only use the compare/diff section.

Answer (score 0):

- you can run RMAN command `validate backup` so you can check the backup before restoring it
- every database block has (or might have) a check sum in it. This is validated during both backup and restore
- Also every datafile has "timestamp" (SCN) of the last modification written in it's header. And the database won't start if these SCN differ.
- you can also check statistics. The view ALL_ALL_TABLES contains number of rows for every table (form the last stats. gathering)

There are many ways, you have to choose on which level you want to validate.